# on Windows 10 Odoo 9 --addons_path error

Tags: windows, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I installed Odoo v9 on Windows 10. Tried to execute it by command:

```
python odoo.py -w odoo -r odoo
```

I created a new filder for custom addons here:

```
C:\odoo\openerp\custom\addons
```

I'm trying to run the process with a custom addons path:

```
C:\odoo>python odoo.py -w odoo -r odoo --addons=C:\odoo\openerp\custom\addons
```

But I always gt an error:

```
    odoo.py: error: option --addons-path: The addons-path 
   'C:\\odoo\\openerp\\custom\\addons' does not seem to a be a valid Addons Directory!
```

What's wrong? I checked the directory is right and i'm running process on Windows command prompt with admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addons directory should contain folders that should each one have the following files:

1. `__init__.py`
2. `__openerp__.py`

and some other custom folders for models and view etc...

check if the addons folder has any other folder that is not structured as above.